# Color doesn't change to particular class item when styled

Tags: html, css

This is the html code i am using.......

```
<ul id="top_options">
<li>Discussions</li> 
<li>Tags</li> 
<li>Users</li>
<li class="selected_top_option">Unaddressed</li> 
<li>New Discussion</li> </ul>
```

and this is the CSS part i am using for the above code...

```
#top_options
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#top_options li
{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:#ADADAD;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#top_options li:hover
{
    background-color:#FF8000;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.selected_top_option
{
    background-color:#F00;
    border:dotted;
}
```

The Problem is the 'Unaddressed' list item should be displayed in #F00 background color, but it is being displayed in #ADADAD background color, but it is getting the border specified. What is the point i am missing here.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) - when you define the same CSS attribute in two different ways for the same element, the CSS attribute in the more specific selection method is the one applied.

`#top_options li` is more specific than `.selected_top_option` and so its definition of `background-color` is the one applied. Think of it this way - there can only be one thing with that `id` so that is very specific, but there can be many things with that `class`, so that is less specific. As such, the `id` wins out.

Based on the [linked HTML Dog article](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) (this isn't *exactly* how specificity is calculated, as it ignores `!important` for instance, but it's a great quick and easy calculation method), the specificity is:

```
.selected_top_option = 10 (1 class selector)
#top_options li = 101 (1 id selector + 1 element selector)
```

So in this case, 101 is higher (i.e. more specific) and wins out whenever there's a conflict between these two.

Another good article on specificty is [this Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and there are plenty more on Google.

The solution is to make `.selected_top_option` more specific. I'd recommend either:

```
#top_options li.selected_top_option { /* your css here */ } 
.selected_top_option { background-color: #F00 !important; /* rest of css */ }
```

However, I'd recommend against the `!important` in most cases, simply because it makes it more complicated to override later.

Comment: does this mean that a div with and id is less specific than a class item? how does the hierarchy go??

Comment: +1 Mine is a quick fix, yours is an elegant, in-depth explanation.

Comment: An id is more specific than a class (an id can only reference one thing after all, but there could be many things with a class). As such the id always wins out. As per the end of my answer, either also include the id with the class, or add `!important` to your class.

Answer (score 3):

```
.selected_top_option
{
    background-color:#F00 !important;
    border:dotted;
}
```